# CodenameOne - Adding text to a floating action button

Tags: codenameone

Using Floating Action Buttons in CodenameOne is great, but now I would like to add some text to describe the buttons use. I see there is a .setText but this doesn't seem to do anything, is there a way of doing this in code or do I need to add the text to the bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating action buttons in material design don't have text next to them so this isn't an option. Using an image probably won't work correctly and will cause an issue.

Based on the material guidelines the action of the FAB should be obvious and if it isn't you shouldn't use a FAB.

`setText` is there for actions you add under the button using `createSubFAB`.